# jade not executing javascript functions

Tags: node.js, pug

I have this jade file

```
- if (transactions != "")
    table
        th Site Name
        th Deadline
        th Delete Transaction

        each item in transactions
            tr
                td= item.item_name
                td
                    span(id='countdown'+item.timeout)= item.timeout
                td
                    span(style='cursor: pointer;', onclick='deleteTransaction('+item.uniqueId+')')= "X"

    button(id='confirmButton', onclick='confirm();', value="Confirm", name="Confirm")= "Confirm"
    script
        fillCountdown(transactions);
```

I don't understand why the function `fillCountdown` in the last line is never called. I have to say that this page is loaded in a Chrome extension, in the popup, but I guess nothing changes.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the HTML produced by this jade template. Maybe that will give you an idea.

Comment: The HTML doesn't show the `script` tag at all, I already checked that before asking here. And JavaScript doesn't give any error at all.

Comment: try script(type="text/javascript")

Comment: Thanks, now it shows it but it doesn't execute it. Very strange.

Comment: `script` code gets executed on the client, not the server. do you intend to do that?

Comment: Of course I intend to do that. I figured later that the problem was that this code is loaded within an AJAX request and the HTML is filled via `.innerHTML` so it's kind of normal if it's not executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the indentation used in jade. After the script tag, you need to give two spaces indentation and then define the function. For e.g.:

```
body
  script(type='text/javascript')
    function something() {
    alert("Inappropriate Value")
    }
```

Also check if the script tag is properly indented with the body tag. If you are defining a function inside the script tag, check the script tag is at only one level indentation with the body tag.. In your code snippet it is not clear if the script tag is nested inside the "if" case or properly aligned with the body tag. When I copied your code snippet, your function "fillCountdown" was indented with 4 spaces with the script tag. In jade the indentation is of two spaces.. Hope this solves your problem.